# Why is the SampleCount in CloudWatch plots too low?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I've started a script using Amazon SageMaker that repeatedly prints a log message `Finished game X` where `X` is incremented each time. I want to plot the progress of that script using CloudWatch, so I defined a custom metric.

However, when I visualize this metric in CloudWatch and choose `SampleCount`, the numbers are way too low:

[image: SampleCount is too low]

According to this plot, there would be no more than 4 (number of data points) * 250 (maximal value) = 1000 samples. However, in my logs I can see that more than 5k games were played and there's a log entry for each game.

Why does this happen, and how can the SampleCount be used correctly?

In this instance I can work around it by e.g. plotting the value of `X`. But that shows the total number of games played so far, not the number of games played in the last e.g. 15 minutes, I'd need to compute the rate of games manually.

[image: Plotting Maximum works as expected]

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen

[`SampleCount`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Statistics-definitions.html) is the number of data points **during the period**.

From your data point count, I can tell that your period is set to 15 minutes (1 data point for 2:00, 2:15, 2:30, 2:45 etc.) so `SampleCount` is correct here.

If you’re hovering over a point at 2:45 and it’s showing 244, it means that 244 data points were collected during that period. You have 244 data points for the past 15 minutes.

> and how can the SampleCount be used correctly?

If you want to see the '1000~' figure, that would be the `SampleCount` for the whole hour (as per your calculation) so you need to change your period to 1 hour.

Alternatively, I assume you don't want to change your period and want to see the cumulative `SampleCount` sum up to that point on the graph (over the currently visible range).

In that case, use [Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html). You need the `METRICS()` function that returns all the metrics in the request, and the `SUM()` function to get the sum of the values of all data points in the metric.

Combine the two for the `SUM(METRICS())` expression, that returns a time series that when plotted, it should give you what you're looking for - the sum of the `SampleCount` data points.

Comment: Sorry, my question might have been unclear: From the first plot (and the logs) I can see that the total number of games played is 5314. For each game, there's one log entry (I checked that). So there should be 5k data points, but the second plot only accounts for less than 1k. What happened to the rest of them?

Comment: @Christopher In that case, yes unclear. Are you looking to get a running sum of the log count? What do you want to see that you can't see in the first plot?

Comment: I want to get an accurate count of how many of those log messages were created every e.g. 15 minutes. My understanding was that SampleCount would do just that, but apparently it doesn't? When there are 5k logs, and my SampleCount has 4 points in the plot, the sum of those 4 values should be 5k.
In this instance I could use the first plot. But what if e.g. I'm logging the training loss at each iteration, and at some point want to check how many iterations were trained every 15 minutes? If SampleCount would work correctly, it would tell me exactly that.